# How can I import a javascript library in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jshint

When I am loading my page I include a javascript library that is used to create graphs with the Google api. I am handling this with CoffeeScript in the front end. According to the tutorial I am initiating the library like: `data = new google.visualization.DataTable();`.

When I am parsing my produced JS code from CoffeeScript with JSHint I am getting an error that google is not defined. How can I show to the parser that the library is actually loaded and the object exists?

```
data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

PROBLEM:
'google' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to call it from the window object like

`data = new window.google.visualization.DataTable();`

and it stopped complaining.

Comment: Why is it working with window? I cannot see any class named like this in the API? Did you encountered any other problem while doing charts with coffee?

Comment: window is the global function wrapper for the DOM object. So when you import google graphs library is getting attached to it, If I understood right, no I haven't had any other issues.